# Why this python script does not work?

Tags: python-2.7

Update 1: the last line of code `sorted_xlist = sorted(xlist).extend(sorted(words_cp))` should be changed to:

```
sorted_xlist.extend(sorted(xlist))
sorted_xlist.extend(sorted(words_cp))
```

Update 1: Code is updated to solve the problem of changing length of `words` list.

This exercise of list functions is from Google's Python Introduction course.  I don't know why the code doesn't work in Python 2.7.  The goal of the code is explained in annotation portion.

```
# B. front_x
# Given a list of strings, return a list with the strings
# in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first.
# e.g. ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] yields
# ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
# Hint: this can be done by making 2 lists and sorting each of them
# before combining them.

def front_x(words):
  words_cp = []
  words_cp.extend(words)
  xlist=[]
  sorted_xlist=[]
  for i in range(0, len(words)):
    if words[i][0] == 'x':  
      xlist.append(words[i])
      words_cp.remove(words[i])  
  print sorted(words_cp) # For debugging
  print sorted(xlist)    # For debugging 
  sorted_xlist = sorted(xlist).extend(sorted(words_cp))    
  return sorted_xlist
```

Update 1: Now error message is gone.

```
front_x
['axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['xaa', 'xzz']
  X  got: None expected: ['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['xaa', 'xcc']
  X  got: None expected: ['xaa', 'xcc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
['xanadu', 'xyz']
  X  got: None expected: ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

The splitting of the original list works fine.  But the merging doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are running this code? As a function definition, the code you have provided is not problematic. The error you are getting seems to indicate you're not passing in a valid argument.

Comment: I use `ctrl+b` to test the code in Sublime.  The Google's exercise provided some testing lists and will tell you whether the output of the function is correction or not.

Comment: Will you also want someone to do your homework for 2-5? http://ce.sharif.edu/~mtabrizi/problems.htm

Comment: Not about homework.  It is about learning and understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over a sequence as you're changing its length.

Imagine if you start off with an array

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

When you remove the first two items from it, now you have:

```
arr = ['c','d','e']
```

But you're still iterating over the length of the original array.  Eventually you get to i > 2, in my example above, which raises an IndexError.

Comment: your comment makes sense.  The error message is gone now.  But the final code is still not right.  Give me 5 minutes to update the question.

Comment: Ahh, I got it, just change the last line of code to `sorted_xlist.extend(sorted(xlist))
  sorted_xlist.extend(sorted(words_cp))` and now everything works!  Thanks a lot!